# QUdp socket stop receiving packets in QT?

Tags: qt, networking, udp, qt4, qudpsocket

I have written code to receive UDP packets from a source. It works fine in the beginning. After receiving 'n' number of packets, it stops receiving packets from the connected ip and port. Note: i had checked that the udp socket is already in use and buffer is not overflowing.

Answer (score 1):

There is not such a problem in Qt4. I have some sockets that receiving and sending packets for days with periods like 50 ms. Maybe you should share your code and even some logs to get a more precise answer.